# Infowindow close event listener on gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have some list of markers being shown in google map. Now I want to do some additional things when I close the infowindow.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps.map.visibleInfoWindow,'closeclick',function()
{
    do_something();
});
```

It doesn't seem to working. Please provide some tutorial or code block to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override [the way infowindows are created](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/gmaps4rails/google/objects/marker.coffee#L32).

Something like this:

```
old_method = Gmaps4Rails.Google.Marker.prototype.createInfoWindow

Gmaps4Rails.Google.Marker.prototype.createInfoWindow = function(){
  old_method();
  // then access the infowindow with: this.infowindow and add whatever you need
}
```

---

For 1.x, do the same but with: `Gmaps4RailsGoogle.prototype.createInfoWindow`

Comment: When I run this Gmaps4Rails.Google.Marker.prototype.createInfoWindow I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'Marker' of undefined. I use gem version : gmaps4rails (1.5.6)

Comment: oh ok, I've to check for this version